# Debugging in wordpress gives undefined method sd()

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

I am debugging a wordpress plugin. For  debugging  tried dd(), sd() etc which results in error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dd()

Comment: are you using a plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/laravel-dd/

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this

```
function my_plugin_log($value) {
    return @file_put_contents(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/my-plugin-logs.txt', "\n ---- " . var_export($value, true) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

so you can use like

```
my_plugin_log('any var or any string here');
```

It will create the log file in **wp-content** dir, it do not kill the php instances also like `die()`

Answer (score 0):

dd(). dd is a helper method in Laravel. This package will add the dd to your application

You cant use it in Wordpress

Comment: As an alternative you could make use of `print_r()` and `var_dump()`

Comment: what is the equivalent tool in wordprss

Comment: `var_dump($yourData); die();`

Comment: use var_dump() or print_r()